# Positioning 4 figures in to two pair on one line

Tags: positioning, subfloats, gnuplot

currently I have something that looks like;

[image]

These images have come from epslatex plots from gnuplot. So my code looks like

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \hspace{-5.2em}
 \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
 \input{initialpolar1.tex}
  \label{fig:sub1}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \input{finalpolar1.tex}
 \label{fig:sub2}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{These two next to each other.}
 \label{fig9}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[H]
 \hspace{-5.2em}
 \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
 \input{initialpolar2.tex}
 \label{fig:sub1}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
 \input{finalpolar2.tex}
 \label{fig:sub2}
  \end{subfigure}
 \caption{And these two.}
 \label{fig9}
      \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

How would I get this so that the top two pictures are next to each other? (basically so that the left of the right graph touches the colourbox label numbers of the left). And the bottom two pictures. And then place both pairs on the same line but separated by a distance? Then the whole thing centred in the page. i.e. I want to go from

A      B

C      D

to

AB  CD

Putting fbox around my images I get something like this

[image]

Could this cause issues with what I need to achieve?

Comment: `\begin{figure}\centering \input{initialpolar1.tex} \input{finalpolar1.tex}\hfill \input{initialpolar2.tex} \input{finalpolar2.tex}\caption{Stuff}\end{figure}` or do you need to cross reference the subfigures?

Comment: Where comes `subfigure` from? Your example does not compile. If you use `subfigure` package, it is deprecated

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `subcaption` defines a `subfigure` environment used like this. The `subfigure` package only defines a `\subfigure` command I think.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I never used `subcaption` before. It was not clear from the 'MWE'

Comment: Hey Torb, I tried that. It seems to put each image underneath each other. I placed fbox around my images and found that their borders are actually quite large, see OP. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Please fix your example so that it demonstrates the problem, as posted it just generates `! LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.

Comment: Apologies but I have so many packages installed it's hard to remember which ones are necessary to mention. I think the subcaption package (edited now) is what was necessary.

Comment: That would of course be an issue, as you can't fit four that wide images in a line. Make gnuplot output plots without all that whitespace if you can.

Comment: Yes, you should fix your gnuplot code to produce images of the correct size and without huge margins. Ask for this at stackoverflow and provide your code, I'll be happy to help you there :)

Comment: It isn't hard to remember which packages are needed, you just need to test the example before posting (`H` is still not defined although that error isn't reported)

Comment: Thanks all, but the gnuplot borders were causing me issues. I did reduce these borders as much as I knew I could and then followed asis' suggestion, but the borders were still too large to fit 4 images on a single level. In the meantime I've given up and shoved all plots how I wanted in an image editor, then imported that as a single image. Unfortunately I lose image quality in doing so. See my stackoverflow post for my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596518/need-to-reduce-this-whitespace-but-seem-to-be-at-a-limit-at-how-much-i-can-gnu

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about correcting the margins of gnuplot images and is in the meanwhile being asked at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{subfig} 

 \begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[A]{\label{fig1}\rule{2cm}{4cm}}
    \,
    \subfloat[B]{\label{fig2}\rule{2cm}{4cm}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[C]{\label{fig3}\rule{2cm}{4cm}}
    \,
    \subfloat[D]{\label{fig4}\rule{2cm}{4cm}}

    \caption{Put caption here where \ref{fig1} \ldots; \ref{fig2} \ldots; \ref{fig3} \ldots; and \ref{fig4} \ldots}
\end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

This is the screenshot.

[image]